# Laravel 8 with breadcrumbs add dynamic page title

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-8, bootstrap-5

I'm using **[laravel-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs)** package by **diglactic** with **laravel 8**  forked from **[davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs)** I'm trying to add **dynamic page title** based on this **breadcrumbs package**.

what I mean by **dynamic page title** ? let's imagine that every page I have it contain a **page title section** like this :

**HTML:** *(Every Page it have this section below the navbar)*

```
<section class="py-5 text-center container">
    <div class="row py-lg-5">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="fw-bold mb-4">Page Title Here</h1> // Dynamic Page Title Here
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you use blade template engine?

Comment: yeah this section is inside a .blade.php file

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own breadcrumb. First you should generate blade component something like `php artisan make:component breadcrumb` and then look at the code, I use it anyway and it success

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        // your prev code
        view()->share('currentPath', explode('/', substr_replace(request()->path(), '', 0, 3)));
    }
```

**componenents/breadcrumb.blade.php**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="breadcrumbs">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item pl-0">
                        <a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    @foreach ($paths as $path)
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item pl-0 text-capitalize 
                    {{ $loop->last ? 'active' : '' }}">
                        <a href="{{ url($path) }}">
                            {{ str_replace('-', ' ', $path) }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And use it in any view like this

```
<x-breadcrumb :paths="$currentPath" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@yield` to cahnge a section of your template dynamically.
check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#defining-a-layout) for more info.

Comment: thank you but I'm not looking for >@yield('title') in my question I request how I can create dynamic page title based on laravel-breadcrumbs package by diglactic read my question well please thanks

Answer (score 0):

The @yield is use to dynamic title

here i am create a `template.blade.php` file and `title.blade.php`.

the `title.blade.php` is extends `template.blade.php` file and title can dynamic is work perfectly.

template.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    The title is dynamically
</body>
</html>
```

title.blade.php

```
@extends('template')
@section('title')
    My Title
@endsection
```

Comment: thank you but I'm not looking for >@yield('title') in my question I request how I can create dynamic page title based on laravel-breadcrumbs package by diglactic.